# Graft vector into dataframe column

Tags: r, dplyr

How would someone insert a vector of values into consecutive `NA` values in a dataframe? It seems like it should be a simple task but thinking more on it, this seems like something that would be relatively uncommon. I couldn't find anything in a search but I may be using the wrong search terms.

I tried a couple things but neither were really anything close to correct.

I'm think I could do this in `base` with subsetting but I would like a `dplyr` solution.

Sample Data:

```
df <- tibble(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), 
             col2 = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,7))

df    
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  col1   col2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         1
2 B         2
3 C        NA
4 D        NA
5 E        NA
6 F        NA
7 G         7

v <- c(3,4,5,6)
```

Trying to insert vector `v` into `col2` to replace the `NA`s and obtain the desired solution:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  col1   col2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         1
2 B         2
3 C         3
4 D         4
5 E         5
6 F         6
7 G         7
```

Comment: `is.na(df)<-v` is the way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), 
             col2 = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,7))
v <- c(3,4,5,6)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(col2 = replace(col2, is.na(col2), v))
#>   col1 col2
#> 1    A    1
#> 2    B    2
#> 3    C    3
#> 4    D    4
#> 5    E    5
#> 6    F    6
#> 7    G    7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, base R approach would be:

```
v = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
df[is.na(df$col2), 2] = v
```